# Github action No event triggers defined in `on`

Tags: github, yaml, pipeline, github-actions

I have created a pipeline and i want to trigger every time I push on any branch

There is my `default.yml` :

```
name: default

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - '*'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: CocoaPod Install
      run: pod install
    - name: Force xcode version
      run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.2.1.app
    - name: Build
      run: ./pipelines.sh build
```

When i push this on github, I have this error

> No event triggers defined in `on`

[image]

Comment: Might either be a one off instance of error or there would be an indentation issue in your yaml file. I tried the same config and it's working fine.

Comment: Could you please try pushing the same again and triggering the build?

Comment: Use `on: [push]` - no branches, no nothing.

Comment: @DannyB It is possible to define branches.

Comment: But the question is about "i want to trigger every time I push on any branch". Therefore: no need to define branches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can trigger all branches just by using

```
on: push
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#example-using-a-single-event

Remove - '*'

Your workflow file seems fine. Have you checked all indentation.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error from a commit where I have only edited the workflow yaml file but nothing else. It was triggered normally after editing and commiting other files.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I'm not sure what causes this error either. It seems to be some combination of syntax or parsing error covered up by a less useful error.

For me,

- checking whitespace
- making sure there was a line-break between a comment block and the events block
- switching from `paths` to `paths-ignore`

One of those things fixed it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I added to the `.github/workflows` folder a yamllint config yaml file. Because it was located in that folder, it was evaluated as a workflow file, but it actually wasn't (hence no trigger specified). I fixed it by moving the file out of that directory, to `.github`.