# dependabot: Error : .github#L1 No event triggers defined in `on`

Tags: github-actions, dependabot

I'm trying to setup dependabot on a Github repo.

Here's my config file:

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "pip"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    open-pull-requests-limit: 10
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Annotations
1 error
Error : .github#L1
No event triggers defined in `on`
```

[This error can occur in case of parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68061192/4653485). But I adapted this file from a copy-paste of [an example in the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-dependencies-updated-automatically/enabling-and-disabling-version-updates). Besides, I validated the yaml file with a validation tool.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That error suggests it's being parsed as an _actions_ file (which is what the linked question is about); you've put `dependabot.yml` in `.github/workflows/` not just `.github/`.

Comment: Link to the repo confirms what @jonrsharpe wrote.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-dependencies-updated-automatically/configuration-options-for-dependency-updates): "You must store this file in the `.github` directory of your repository."

Comment: Oh boy. Glad I asked, cause I could have been searching for a looooong time. I think I was tricked by vim because there was already a workflows directory in .github and nothing else so when creating the dependabot file it ended up in workflows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GitHub parses `dependabot.yml` as an action file because I put it in `.github/workflows/` by mistake.

It should be `.github/dependabot.yml`.

Comment: This is such a common mistake you'd think Github would show a warning or something